# Do I use the apostrophe when referring possessivizing "humans"?

Tags: word-usage

I want to talk about what humans usually eat.

> Do you use humans’ diet in English?

Thanks

Comment: An example sentence, using humans', would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you Jim.I want to talk about foods(meats,fruits,vegetables,..) that all of people in the world eat in their daily lives.I think The human diet is correct,isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The human diet.**

It's the use of singular as representative of whole group/species.

It's like you hear in nature movies: "*The White Rhino is on the brink of extinction*" - it isn't about the specific one rhino in the footage, but about the species as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

As SF pointed out, 'humans' refers to a group, so the apostrophe would be placed in the singular position. e.g. "Because primates are carnivorous, the human's diet includes meat."